# Python File Matching

Tags: python-2.7

Currently stuck with a small task, I have two .txt files that I would like to find any matching words that appear in both and output the result to a new file, however the code below only displays blank file, any idea what I need to change or look at.

```
file1 example    file2 example
12345 565        543252 
54321 ff df      12345  
0000  ff f0      11111
```

Ideally as 12345 is matched in both files it should print the line 12345 565 from file1 into the output file.

```
with open('Results.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('matches.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that first line of `file1` is actually:

```
12345 565
```

And second line from `file2` is only:

```
12345
```

Your code won't work because `intersect` will be trying to match this different lines.

What you can do is:

```
with open('Results.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as file2:
        a = set(x.split()[0] for x in file1)
        b = [x.rstrip() for x in file2]
        same = a.intersection(b)

same.discard('\n')

print same
```

Output: `set(['12345'])`

Notice this method uses only first column from `file1` so any other match with other columns won't work. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! Out of interest is it possible to print the full line from file1? i.e. 12345 565?